# Add a new value to insert it

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

hello i have this function insertion works very well

```
function add_post(){

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_id','User Id','trim|required');
        //set msg if form validation false
        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){

            $response = array('status' => FAIL, 'message' => strip_tags(validation_errors()));
            $this->response($response);
        }

        $is_exist = $this->common_model->getsingle(USERS,array('userId'=>$this->post('user_id')));
        if($is_exist){
            $is_active = $this->common_model->getsingle(USER_COUPON,array('user_id'=>$is_exist->userId,'status'=>1));
            $data['user_id'] = $is_exist->userId;
            $data['user_coupon_id'] = $is_active->userCouponId;
            $data['email'] = $is_exist->email;
            $result = $this->common_model->insertData(USER_COUPON_SCAN,$data);
            $response = array('status' => SUCCESS, 'message' => "success");
            $this->response($response);
        }

        $response = array('status' => FAIL,'message' =>"No record found please try again");
        $this->response($response);
    }
```

the function recovers a single value user_id,I want to get a new value send by post (name admin_id) and isert in user_coupan_scan table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that your code is working well, You can receive posted admin_id in following way.

```
function add_post(){

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_id','User Id','trim|required');
    //set msg if form validation false
    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){

        $response = array('status' => FAIL, 'message' => strip_tags(validation_errors()));
        $this->response($response);
    }

    $is_exist = $this->common_model->getsingle(USERS,array('userId'=>$this->post('user_id'))); // You may need to change $this->post('user_id') to $this->input->post('user_id')
    if($is_exist){
        $is_active = $this->common_model->getsingle(USER_COUPON,array('user_id'=>$is_exist->userId,'status'=>1));
        $data['admin_id'] = $this->input->post('admin_id'); //  make sure that the column name in your table is admin_id
        $data['user_id'] = $is_exist->userId;
        $data['user_coupon_id'] = $is_active->userCouponId;
        $data['email'] = $is_exist->email;
        $result = $this->common_model->insertData(USER_COUPON_SCAN,$data);
        $response = array('status' => SUCCESS, 'message' => "success");
        $this->response($response);
    }

    $response = array('status' => FAIL,'message' =>"No record found please try again");
    $this->response($response);
}
```

In above answer, I have added one line i.e. receiving admin_id in post data.

```
$data['column_name_in_your_table'] = $this->input->post('name_in_post_data');
```

To receive data from post method you can do it like this

```
$some_name = $this->input-post('name');
```

Hope it helps.